# Why can't I apply opacity on background HEX :root CSS variable?

Tags: css

I have :root css variable `--color: #ff0000;`. I use **hex codes, not rgb/rgba.**
I am trying to make this color variable `opacity: .2;`. But I can't get it to work.

I tried this and some other options. How can I put opacity on a HEX css variable?

```
tr {
    background: rgba(var(--theme-color), 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
:root {
  --theme-color: #ff0000;
}
tr {
    background: rgba(var(--theme-color), 0.2);
}
```

The browser is just taking that literally. You end up with

```
tr {
    background: rgba(#ff0000, 0.2);
}
```

which is invalid syntax for `rgba`. If you open your browser console and inspect the styles, you'll see that it's invalid.

You have a few options:

1. Get the rgb equivalent of your hex color and use that instead. In your case, the rgb equivalent of `#ff0000` is `255, 0, 0`, so you could do `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)`.
2. Set the opacity in 8-character hex form. See [Hexadecimal color code for transparency](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4). In your case it'd be `#ff000033`.
3. If you are using a preprocessor like Sass, you can use a color function to programmatically set the value from the opaque color you have in a variable. For example, Sass has the [`transparentize` function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#transparentize). Other preprocessors have equivalents, so you can Google for that.
4. Use the actual CSS `opacity` property.

   ```
   tr {
     background: var(--theme-color);
     opacity: 0.2;
   }
   ```

   Note, however, that this isn't strictly the same as changing the alpha value in a `background-color`. Opacity affects the entire element and its children, so you may have to change how you do your HTML/CSS to pull off the same visual effect.

Comment: Sadly for this project 1, 2 and 4 are not an option. I did not know Sass had a transparentize function, that may be an option! Maybe I can make a mixin for that.

Answer (score 0):

It does actually work like this:

```
:root {
    --color: 255,255,0;
  }
  body {
    background: rgba(var(--color), 0.5) !important;
  }
```

Comment: Thing is I don't use rgb/rgba, I use hex codes.